# Unable to login to Stack Overflow in IE using my Google account

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, internet-explorer

I have recently been having a clean up on my computer so deleted all of my temporary files etc.. when I returned to the StackOverflow login page I was logged out.

Now, each time I click on the Google button to try and login, I get this error message in the console and nothing else happens (and I stay logged out.)
I can still login using my mobile and I can login with other browsers so this appears to be a IE (v.11) issue.

[image]

Are there any issues which anyone is aware of which could be causing this or is it a new "anti-IE" incentive?

Comment: No issues here - are you able to access the https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/auth.en.js file directly?

Comment: Yes, @JarrodDixon I can get the file, the issue appears to be something in the file. (line 1, column 927) when I try to debug it, the cursor stops at `if (localStorage)` but as the file is minified it's not that easy to get much more info.

Comment: Oops, I misread your report.  I can't reproduce in IE 11.0.9600.18205, but I did find [this promising blog post](https://grekai.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/localstorage-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/).  Maybe give that a shot?

Comment: Also, from SuperUser, some extra info - http://superuser.com/questions/560414/major-issues-after-updating-ie10 - could be corrupted local storage.

Comment: That first link you shared has fixed it!! "Clear the Preserve Favourite Site Data check box to delete all storage areas, regardless of source." Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)